# Recover /usr/lib64 folder in Red Hat linux

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

First I backed up **/usr/lib64** folder by copying it including all its content and named it **lib64_bk**, and then I made some modifications on the original folder, because of that I found myself on the need of restoring the back up folder, however I did it the wrong way.

The first thing I did was to rename the original folder **from lib64 to lib64_old** by using this command:

```
mv /usr/lib64 /usr/lib64_old
```

And I was planning to restore the back up by renaming the other folder from **lib64_bk to lib64**

After this, whenever I run commands like `ls` or `cp` I get a message like this:

```
bash: /usr/bin/ls: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Please help me, I certainly realize that I have messed up the OS installation, now I need to know if there's a way to recover it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you rename the lib64_bk folder back to lib64 yet? If yes, were any other changes made to other folders? Just renaming it looks like it should "roll back" the peoblem change. Do you have a live DVD/USB to use?

Comment: I haven't don't that because I'm not able to. I get the same error message when trying to use mv command to rename it, in a few words the terminal is useless. No I don't have a DVD or USB, but it will be useful to know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bring back the `/usr/lib64` directory temporary by running these commands:

```
cd /usr
/sbin/sln lib64_old lib64
```

`sln` is statically linked, so it will not need the `/usr/lib64` directory to run.

Comment: it's work, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind rebooting, and have another linux live DVD/USB...

1. boot into the live linux
2. mount the partition that has your main OS's `/usr` folder
3. rename/copy your backup folder from `lib64_bk` back to `lib64`
4. boot into your main OS

If the only change was renaming that folder, then changing it back should fix things.

---

Without rebooting, you might have luck with another program that can rename / copy / move folders that doesn't need anything in `/usr/lib64`, but I'm not sure what  might work, maybe a perl script/program?

Or if you can still create a link, it might be possible to link the old `lib64-bk` so you see it instead of the broken `lib64`.